# Slow load of image in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I am having an issue with my code in firefox. I have this div slider I have created. However, it is only lagging in firefox and it auto corrects images after a couple seconds whereas in chrome and safari it works fine. What I am doing is having a total of 10 divs centered side by side with only 9 showing. On left button click i will show the element on the right thats hidden and hide the element all the way to the left. On right button click I do the opposite. Here is an example with images.

Normal:

[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9]

left click:

[2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10]

right click:

[10][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]

Here is a working code pen example I made please open in chrome then compare in firefox. I set the image links to links online but normally I am using local images of size 200kbs.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Angatvir/pen/qyYvjY)

Here is what happens on left click (in code)

```
function leftClick() {
  var images = $(".my-image");
  //start switching
  $('#image-1').attr('id' , 'image-10');
  $('#image-2').attr('id' , 'image-1');
  $('#image-3').attr('id' , 'image-2');
  $('#image-4').attr('id' , 'image-3');
  $('#image-5').attr('id' , 'image-4');
  $('#image-6').attr('id' , 'image-5');
  $('#image-7').attr('id' , 'image-6');
  $('#image-8').attr('id' , 'image-7');
  $('#image-9').attr('id' , 'image-8');
  $('#image-10').attr('id' , 'image-9');
  //show 1-9 while hiding 10
  var refreshedImages = $(".my-image");
  for (var i = 1; i < refreshedImages.length; i++) {
    var intValue = i.toString();
    var turnOnImage = document.getElementById("image-" + intValue);
    turnOnImage.style.display = "block";
  }
  var turnOffImage = document.getElementById("image-" + "10");
  turnOffImage.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Pleased to meet you too, my name is [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: It's lagging because it is not set up in an Array? Sorry I am new to programming and I understand my code is ugly.

Comment: Checked your codepen in Chrome and Firefox and my guess is that the issue is in your css. That said, there is quite a bit of duplicative code that makes it harder to spot the culprit. You might consider applying css styles to classes that you can assign to your html elements that share most of their styles in common, then you can apply just the unique styles using your element ids. I think it may help your troubleshooting. Depending on what else you plan to do with your numbered images, you may not even need javascript at all for that effect (but first things first).

Comment: Ok so remove duplicate code that is in the image tags in css and set to the parent? while keeping unique styles to just those div ids. Thank you so much for your help hopefully this helps troubleshoot.

Comment: Ben, I just want to thank you I narrowed down the problem to the banners with your idea. All your help was much appreciated.